# Node.js unixODBC connect Error in npm odbc

Tags: javascript, node.js, odbc

I'm using ODBC to access my database in Node.js
But weird error occurs when Node tries to connect to the database.

odbc version : 1.2.1
Node version : 8.16.0

```
var db = require("odbc")()
var cn = "DSN=MYCONNECT;"
var con = db.open(cn,function(err){
   if(err){
      return console.log(err);
   }
});
```

Error :

```
{ Error: [unixODBC]
  errors: [ { message: '[unixODBC] ', state: 'I' } ],
  error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',
  message: '[unixODBC] ',
  state: 'I' }
```

What is the content of this error?

Has someone ever stumbled into this problem and can help?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you look at https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-retrieve-the-error-code-and-SQLSTATE-in-node-odbc ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [odbc git documentation](https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc) v1.2.1, there is a guide to enable debug options. try enabling debug option and see debug messages.

---

#### Debug

If you would like to enable debugging messages to be displayed you can add the
flag `DEBUG` to the defines section of the `binding.gyp` file and then execute
`node-gyp rebuild`.

```
<snip>
'defines' : [
  "DEBUG"
],
<snip>
```

---

I hope this is helpful. Thanks.